# How to fix math functions not being found from "cuda_fp16.h"

Tags: math, cuda

I'm writing a memory-heavy CUDA computation program. I need to use mathematical functions, like the ones in math.h within my kernel. So I did some research and stumbled upon "cuda_fp16.h", which is supposed to add a lot of mathematical functions to use on the device. However, if I want to use one of those math functions (e.g. `cos(i)` which is part of this library), upon compilation, it tells me that I cannot run a `__host__` function on the device. Its clear to me that this is impossible, but the cuda_fp16.h library should exactly add `__device__` functions for math. Within the "cuda_fp16.h", there are errors saying that the type __half is not defined.

I have looked at the definition of the `cos()` that I was using, and it leads me to something within math.h. So my guess is that it just takes the function from there instead of cuda_fp16.h

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cuda_fp16.h"

__global__ void computation(double x, double y) //function that should upon being called compute the cosine of y.
{
    x = cos(y);
}
```

This is a very simple example of what I am trying to do; just to get the kernel to compute some kind of mathematical function of a value.

I expect the whole thing to be able to compile, since I included the library that would allow such a function to be computed by a `__device__` function. However it does not compile, and tells me that I can not call the `__host__` function cos on the device.

Comment: Why are `x` and `y` of type `double`?

Comment: cuda_fp16.h is an include file specifically for half precision floating point. Why do you imagine it will be applicable in your example?

Comment: I'm not sure about CUDA but I think it follows the same rules about pass-by-value as e.g. C, which means the assignment to `x` won't really do anything useful.

Comment: @Shadow I need double precision

Comment: @talonmies How do I have to compute with double precision then?

Comment: On top of everything else obviously wrong, the code in your question compiles  without error for me. There is nothing to fix -- https://pastebin.com/QQXYT1Bt

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the problem is a ```__host__``` function being called from the device, it does not tell me anything about it being expressed wrong.

Comment: @talonmies so it does not tell you that you are calling a ```__host__``` function from the device? I think for me it calls the ```cos()``` function from math.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. In the code itself, I had an `int` instead of a `double` as an argument for the function. If the argument for `cos()` is an int, then it uses the `<math.h>` version of the function instead of the CUDA one. The CUDA one gets called with a `float` and `double`. So the code I posted as an example is how it actually should work, I just hadn't realised that I had given an integer as an argument instead of the actual wanted double.